# decimal format not working for output

Tags: android, decimalformat

i tried to format the data i retrieve from another page and so why does the output is not in the format. by right it should be 2236.29 but it shows 236.29482845736. i use this formatting at my first page and it works.

```
    //page with problem. long output 
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) 
    {
        Double value = extras.getDouble("dist");
        df.format(value);

        milesDistance = value * 0.000621371;
        df.format(milesDistance);

        Double durationValue = extras.getDouble("time");

        Double speedValue = extras.getDouble("velocity");
        Double mphSpeed = speedValue * 2.23694;
        df.format(speedValue);
        df.format(mphSpeed);

        displayDistance=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.finishDistance);
        displayDistance.setText("Distance: " + value + "meters " + milesDistance + "miles" + " Speed: " + speedValue + "m/s");
```

this is my first page where i did the same thing but with no problems.

```
        //page with no problem
        float[] results = new float[1]; 
        Location.distanceBetween(lat3, lon3, myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude(), results);
        System.out.println("Distance is: " + results[0]);               

        dist += results[0];            
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); // adjust this as appropriate
        if(count==1)
        {
              distance.setText(df.format(dist) + "meters");
```

the output is the same for distance and speed for the page with problem(first code)
            }

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
Double value = extras.getDouble("dist");
        System.out.println(String.format("%.2f",value));
```

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of the outer String.format()?

Comment: Cheers, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything. Although this answer doesn't answer his question, it does solve his  problem so +1 for you!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are calling df.format(...) but are ignoring the return value, which is the correctly formatted String representation of the decimal number.

For example, what you need to write is:

```
Double value = extras.getDouble("dist");
String valueString = df.format(value);

...

displayDistance.setText("Distance: " + valueString ...);
```

or simply

```
displayDistance.setText("Distance: " + df.format(value) + "meters " + df.format(milesDistance) + "miles" + " Speed: " + df.format(speedValue) + "m/s");
```